# Behavior of __LINE__ in inline functions

Tags: c++, c, line, inline, c-preprocessor

I have a macro that passes the line number and file name to an error handler:

```
#define SYSTEM_FAILURE (error_code, comment) \
   System_Failure((error_code), (comment), __LINE__, __FILE__);
```

How will the `__LINE__` be resolved when used inside an inlined function?

```
file.h:
inline int divide(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0)
    {
        SYSTEM_FAILURE(ENUM_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO, "divide by zero error");
    }
    return x/y;
}
```

Will `__LINE__` contain the line number within the header file, or the line number of the source file where the inline function is called (assuming compiler does a "paste" in the source code)?

Comment: Can't try it out as behavior may differ on compilers and may not be what the standard states.

Comment: Downvoters:  Why the downvote?  The question arises from using C, inline functions and macros in an embedded system.

Comment: @Thomas, testing this on your own compiler and including the results in your question (thus making it more like `my preprocessor does this, is it standard?`) would have (and still can) neuter many of the downvotes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In C and C++, macros aren't (for the most part) evaluated with any knowledge of the actual code and are processed before the code (hence the name "preprocessor"). Therefore, `__FILE__` would evaluate to "file.h", and `__LINE__` would evaluate to the line number corresponding to the line on which `SYSTEM_FAILURE` appears in file.h.

Answer (score 7):

Since macros are replaced by their definitions before compilation, the `__LINE__` will contain the actual line of the file in which you used the macro. Inlining will not affect this behaviour at all.

Comment: He's talking about the fact that the C++ function is `inline`, not the macro.

Answer (score 6):

`__LINE__` will be the line of the header file since the preprocessor will evaluate it before the compiler will ever see it.